# A suitable word for seizing a property

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, legalese

When a court orders for taking control of a property or real estate by the government in exchange of money, what is the best word for the court action?

For example:

> The court maintains that his real estate shall be ______ by the time he pays his debts.

*Apprehend, seize, detain* ?

Comment: Do you really mean *by the time* or do you mean *until the time*?

Comment: Do you mean *repossessed*?

Comment: Please enhance your example to fully explain the hypothetical situation.

Answer (score 6):

***[Expropriate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expropriate)*** is also used, especially if the property is taken for public use:

> - (Law) to deprive (an owner) of (property), esp by taking it for public use.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 5):

> When a court orders for taking control of a property or real estate by
>   the government in exchange of money, what is the best word for the
>   court action?

I'm assuming you are looking for the term that describes the action of the government.  The action of a court would be to "order" in the case of property taken to resolve a debt, or "find", "review" in the case of taking of property for "public use"

> Eminent domain laws are created by the federal and state legislatures.
>   Courts have the power to **judicially review** the acquisition of
>   land. However, if there are no arbitrary and unreasonable decisions,
>   courts cannot interfere in the decisions of the legislature.
>   <sub>[Stimmel Law](http://stimmel-law.com/en/article/eminent-domain-basic-law)</sub>

**Simple answer: taking**

> [In the United States] when a property is acquired by the government,
>   it is called “taking.”
>  <sub>[Stimmel Law](http://stimmel-law.com/en/article/eminent-domain-basic-law)</sub>

"Taking" comes from the last clause of the Fifth Amendment to the US Constitution.

> **[Takings clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Eminent_domain)**
>
> The Supreme Court has held that the federal government and each state
>   has the power of eminent domain—the power to **take** private property
>   for "public use". The **Takings** Clause, the last clause of the Fifth
>   Amendment, limits the power of eminent domain by requiring that "just
>   compensation" be paid if private property is **taken** for public
>   use.
>  <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Eminent_domain)</sub>

**Long answer**

The power of a government to take control of private property in exchange of money is called by different names depending on the country.  See following quote about **eminent domain** from Wikipedia.  The act of taking the property is expropriation, as given in @Josh61's answer.

> **[Expropriation](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/expropriation)** is the act of a government taking private property; **Eminent Domain** is the legal term describing the government's right to do so.
>  <sub>[legal-dictionary: TheFreeDictionary](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/expropriation)</sub>

I get the impression that the example sentence you give is not related.

If the purpose of taking the property is to pay off a debt then @Chenmunka's answer (sequestrated) is better:

> **[sequestrated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequestration_%28law%29)**
>
> Sequestration (in law) is the act of removing, separating, or seizing
>   anything from the possession of its owner under process of law for the
>   benefit of creditors or the state.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequestration_%28law%29)</sub>

If the purpose is "for public use"

> **[Eminent domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain)**
>
> **Eminent domain** (United States, the Philippines), **compulsory purchase** (United Kingdom, New Zealand, Ireland), **resumption**
>   (Hong Kong), **resumption/compulsory acquisition** (Australia), or
>   **expropriation** (South Africa, Canada) is the power of a state or a national government to take private property for public use. However,
>   it can be legislatively delegated by the state to municipalities,
>   government subdivisions, or even to private persons or corporations,
>   when they are authorized to exercise the functions of public
>   character. The property may be taken either for government use or by
>   delegation to third parties, who will devote it to public or civic use
>   or, in some cases, to economic development. The most common uses of
>   property taken by eminent domain are for government buildings and
>   other facilities, public utilities, highways, and railroads. However,
>   it may also be taken for reasons of public safety, as in the case of
>   Centralia, Pennsylvania. Some jurisdictions require that the condemnor
>   make an offer to purchase the subject property, before resorting to
>   the use of eminent domain.
>
> **Compensation**
>
> American courts have held that the preferred
>   measure of "just compensation" is "fair market value," i.e., the price
>   that a willing but unpressured buyer would pay a willing but
>   unpressured seller in a voluntary transaction, with both parties fully
>   informed of the property's good and bad features.[14] Also, this
>   approach takes into account the property's highest and best use (i.e.,
>   its most profitable use) which is not necessarily its current use or
>   the use mandated by current zoning if there is a reasonable
>   probability of zone change.
>  <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If the property is being seized in order to pay a debt, then the property is [*sequestrated*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+sequester&oq=define+sequester&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i10j0l2j0i10l4j0l2.1049.4969.0.5372.21.19.2.0.0.0.266.2026.1j11j1.13.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.hp..7.14.1903.0.QBWcEXU-8pc).

Sequestration is the placing of property into the control of a trustee who will distribute it amongst creditors.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Confiscate***
>
> take or seize (someone's property) with authority.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confiscate)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please be sure to [use formatting correctly](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [reference your source](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: "Confiscate" does not require that money is given in exchange, which the OP requires.

Answer (score 1):

The term, in the UK at least, is [Compulsory Purchase](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compulsory%20purchase?s=t)

> **noun** 
>   1. purchase of a house or other property by a local authority or government department for public use or to make way for development, regardless of whether or not the owner wishes to sell
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

This leads to the somewhat clumsy-sounding, but accurate:

> The court maintains that his real estate shall be *compulsorily purchased* by the time...

Comment: I think the missing key element here is that there is debt involved.

Answer (score 0):

If your court case is in Scotland, the estate might be *[poinded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poind)*:-

> poind
>
> 1. (Law) to take (property of a debtor) in execution or by way of distress; distrain
> 2. (Law) to impound (stray cattle, etc)
>
> [Collins English Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]